# How to install Linux Mint 17 on SSD and have Home on HDD

Tags: system-installation, hard-disk, ssd, ssd-hdd-hybrid

I have Sony Vaio VGN-NW23NE Laptop and I'm using Linux Mint as my Operating System for about two years, I've currently *Qiana*.

I bought a new 120 GB SSD to speed up my Laptop, but I'm confused about how to use this SSD because there is so much information on internet.

I want to have a fresh install of Linux Mint on SSD where I only want to install software and my Home on HDD where I can have Data like Documents, Movies etc.

I have no partition on HDD and don't want any partition with new install.

Comment: … You have no partitions? That seems… unlikely.

Comment: Do you mean to say you already have your home directories for the current install on the HDD and want to reuse those for the fresh install? If so do you have `/home` in a separate partition (on the HDD), or is that in the root partition?

Comment: Yes it is the root partition.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it during the install process by selecting "something else" when it asks if you want to install, setup dual boot, etc.

Identify your SSD as the / partition, and some partition on your internal drive as /home.  If you are re-importing a /home from another system, be very careful with the "format?" option.

You can also NOT specify anything special, just a / and swap and bootloader and then go back after first boot and set up the /home.  This is handy if you are using software raid, etc. or you're re-using a /home from another system.  Simply run the `blkid` program, get the UUID of the file system, and make an appropriate entry in `/etc/fstab`.  Boot from a livecd, move any files you want to keep from the first boot in the current /home to the partition where /home will be, empty /home, and reboot.  During the boot process, the /etc/fstab will be read, and /home will be the partition/raid device/whtever you specified.

```
darkstar ~ # blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="ba64b205-aae8-4538-a2f2-a420ab9ef2f3" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d46cf327-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="e351dfc1-ca8c-45e6-a798-709b6bf70ef0" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="d46cf327-05"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="80b0bf23-7ba6-482d-98c5-febc1b607e7a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000a5f65-01"
```

So if I want /dev/sdb1 to be /home I would add the following to /etc/fstab

```
UUID=80b0bf23-7ba6-482d-98c5-febc1b607e7a    /home  ext4 errors=remount-ro 0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Mint with `/home` on your SSD. Identify the UUID of your `/home` partition on your HDD. Add the line to `/etc/fstab` to mount this disk on a pass later than `/` gets mounted.

Comment: please provide more specific content to your answer for it to be actually usable